# Mysql Fulltext deny similar column resul

Tags: mysql, full-text-indexing

I have a set Fulltext to some columns like:

```
car normal | car super | car extra
```

And then values like

```
car normal | car super | car extra
normal car  super car    extra car
```

how i get only 1 column result, becouse when i run the query, bring all becouse all columns have car string?

For example, i search with the string : `super car` i expected the result `super car`only, but result comes with `super car, normal car, extra car`

Comment: Could you provide a dbfidde example, because i search usually for rows ans in rare cases for column_names, but iun your cases in am not clear what you are searching

Comment: @nbk tks for atention i edit tell me if now is more clear...

Comment: @MagicHat , Can you post your query?

Answer (score 0):

If you give a full example of data, we could better understand,what you need.
Also you didn't show us your sanitized query, to have a starting point

My take on your question, You have different columns and in that columns are hidden the words car normal , car super , car extra, and you only want to find the exact wording

> ```
> CREATE TABLE tutorial (
> id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
> title VARCHAR(200), 
> description1 TEXT,
> description2 TEXT, 
> description3 TEXT, 
> FULLTEXT(title,description1,description2,description3)
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO tutorial (title,description1,description2,description3) VALUES
> ('ca1','blah blaha car normal blah blah', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
> ('car2','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet','Blah blah car super BLAh BLAH','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
> ('car3','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet','Blah Bla car extra Blah blah'),
> ('car4','Blah Blah normal car Blah blah','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet','Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')
> ;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> SELECT id, title
> , LOCATE('car normal',description1)
> , LOCATE('car normal',description2)
> , LOCATE('car normal',description3)
> FROM tutorial 
> WHERE MATCH(title,description1,description2,description3) AGAINST ('+("car normal")' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title | LOCATE('car normal',description1) | LOCATE('car normal',description2) | LOCATE('car normal',description3)
> -: | :---- | --------------------------------: | --------------------------------: | --------------------------------:
>  1 | ca1   |                                12 |                                 0 |                                 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=768da7a1e63eaa3c74fd56525938937c)*